# There is a way to change react native asset path to a remote url?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just want to update the jsbundles when push react native code. So I want to change the required image path to a remote server url. Just like the following code.

before:

```
imgUrl: require('../assets/img/tool01.jpg')
```

after:

```
imgUrl: 'https://mycdn.com/path/tool01.jpg'
```

When use `react native bundle --asset-dest`, it's only to specify the local output dir for asset files.

Comment: you mean this ? <Image source={uri:'https://mycdn.com/path/tool01.jpg'} />

Comment: yes. But only when I bundle source code for production, not write it in my source code.

Comment: you can write yourself a custom Image component and check on prod or dev mode on it !

Comment: I have develop a babel plugin to resolve the problem. Thank you any way.